Is it possible to bring network interface back up after "ip link set eth0 down"?
I have a docker container running Ubuntu 18.04.
I ran it with the following command, but if I turn an interface down, no matter what I do, even if it says the interface is up, I can no longer have any connection with it.
docker run --hostname=hello.world --cap-add=NET_ADMIN -it test-ubuntu18

Within my container, I used ip link set eth0 down to temporarily disable the network, but once I turned it back on, nothing works.
This is my Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:18.04 as base

# Install base dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y -q --no-install-recommends \
    apt-transport-https build-essential ca-certificates curl dbus git \
    iputils-ping libssl-dev net-tools network-manager vim wget systemd \
    sudo rsyslog

ENV NVM_DIR /root/.nvm
ENV NODE_VERSION 17

RUN curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.7/install.sh | bash \
    && . $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm use default

# Fix rsyslog start up by disable imklog
RUN sed -i 's/module(load="imklog"/#module(load="imklog"/' /etc/rsyslog.conf

ENTRYPOINT service rsyslog start && \
           service dbus start && \
           service network-manager start && \
           bash

Does anyone know whether is possible to re-enable the network with a docker container?
root@hello:~# ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.13.110) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.217.13.110 (172.217.13.110): icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=11.9 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.13.110 (172.217.13.110): icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=14.0 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1002ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 11.982/13.011/14.041/1.035 ms
root@hello:~# ip link set eth0 down
root@hello:~# ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
root@hello:~# ip link set eth0 up  
root@hello:~# ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
root@hello:~# ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
269: eth0@if270: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0


When you run ip link set eth0 down, two things happen:

The link state changes to down and the interface no longer passes any traffic.
Any routes associated with the interface are deleted.

When you run ip link set eth0 up:

The link state changes to up and the interfaces resumes passing traffic.
A device route is created to the network with which the link is associated.

Read the second step above carefully: any additional routes that were in your routing table before you disabled the link will not be re-created.

For example, if I build and run your Dockerfile locally, the container initially has an address:
root@3194a6d67d5d:/# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
40: eth0@if41: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.17.0.2/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

And a routing table:
root@3194a6d67d5d:/# ip route
default via 172.17.0.1 dev eth0
172.17.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.2

After running ip link set eth0 down, we see that the link state of eth0 has changed (but it still has a configured address):
40: eth0@if41: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.17.0.2/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

And the routing table is now empty:
root@3194a6d67d5d:/# ip route
<no output>

When we re-enable the interface by running ip link set eth0 up, the interface returns to its initial configuration:
root@3194a6d67d5d:/# ip addr show eth0
40: eth0@if41: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:ac:11:00:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 172.17.0.2/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

But now the routing table looks like this:
root@3194a6d67d5d:/# ip route
172.17.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.2

Note that there is no default route. Without a default route, your container doesn't know how to reach any addresses other than those to which it is directly connected. Attempts to reach anywhere else will fail:
root@3194a6d67d5d:/# ping -c1 google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

(We're seeing a "Temporary failure in name resolution" here because the container is unable to reach the configured DNS server.)
We can resolve this situation by manually re-creating the default route:
root@3194a6d67d5d:/# ip route add default via 172.17.0.1
root@3194a6d67d5d:/# ip route
default via 172.17.0.1 dev eth0
172.17.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.2

And now things worked as expected:
root@3194a6d67d5d:/# ping -c1 google.com
PING google.com (142.251.41.14) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lga34s40-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.41.14): icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=13.4 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 13.460/13.460/13.460/0.000 ms

